# Moving Short Description in Woo Commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've hunted everywhere to figure out how to move the Product Short Description from the right side of the picture on a Single Product page of Woocommerce into the tabs. I just can't find it anywhere!

Can someone please help me accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Just [remove the `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` callback from the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/5893875b0c03dda7b2d448d1a904ccfad3cdae3f/templates/content-single-product.php#L59):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
```

...and add it directly to a custom [tabs.php template](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/5893875b0c03dda7b2d448d1a904ccfad3cdae3f/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php):

```
woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();
```

Read more about overriding templates [in the docs](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply is there a way to add a customization to functions.php to achieve the same goal?